# A regex to trim URL down to a simple #id

Tags: regex

Could someone suggest a regex that will find every instance of

```
http://example.com/dokuwiki/doku.php/folder:page?do=export_xhtml#id
```

where

- section is a, variable, folder/section in the Wiki
- page is a page in that folder/section
- id refers to the HTML id attribute of div on that page

so it just reads #id?  The end result will be replacing a fully qualified URL to an internal link on that page from

```
<a href="http://example.com/dokuwiki/doku.php/folder:page?do=export_xhtml#id" >
```

to just

```
<a href="#id" >
```

The context here is modifying the exported contents from the Wiki, dokuwiki, to make it suitable for distribution via a CDN.  The absolute links that go into the exported markup you get via export_xhtml are not necessray and are no good for the CDN since as soon as the user touches such a link he/she will end up visiting the full blown wiki.

Comment: What do you mean by 'section is a, variable, folder/section in the Wiki' ? What part of the URL does this refer to?

Comment: You don't need regex then. You need a substring. From # till the end.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: I mentioned variable to make it clear that the folder & page bits are not static text.  They will vary from link-to-link so some form of wildcard search that stops at the ? and then picks up the id after the # is called for. Way beyond my regex skills I am sorry to say.

Comment: @matcheek my original question was perhaps not that well worded.  I need a regex because, see my comment above, the folder & page bits will change with every link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should serve you well:

```
/http:\/\/example.com\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/([^\?]+)[^#]+#(\d+)/
```

I assume that the id is a digit.

From your example URL this will match:

1. dokuwiki/doku.php
2. folder:page
3. 56 (the id)

To just get the id it would be easiest to do:

```
/#\d+$/
```